# VS Code: Unable to resolve path to module with Webpack and Jsconfig in VS code

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, alias

I have a React project I am building in VS Code. I'm using Webpack, so I wanted to add some aliases:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      Config$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'config.js'),
      Css: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/resources/css'),
      Client: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client')
    }
  }
// etc...
```

So I reference content in my project, e.g. in ./src/client/index.js:

```
import 'Css/util.scss';
```

The project runs as expected.
The issue is that VS Code Intellisense does not recognize the aliases, despite the presence of a `jsconfig.json` in my project root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Config": [
        "./config.js"
      ],
      "Css/*": [
        "./src/client/resources/css/*"
      ],
      "Client/*": [
        "./src/client/*"
      ],
    },
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Attempting to auto-complete or navigate to the location of a file loaded with an alias in VS Code fails, and my ESLint picks it up as an error:

[image: Error report]

The [documentation for jsconfig in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_best-practices) said running the `Reload JacaScript Project` command in the Code Command Palette might solve the issue, but that command is not available to me. I am running:

> Version: 1.32.3 (user setup)
>   Commit: a3db5be9b5c6ba46bb7555ec5d60178ecc2eaae4
>   Date: 2019-03-14T23:43:35.476Z
>   Electron: 3.1.6
>   Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
>   Node.js: 10.2.0 V8: 6.6.346.32 OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763

I've looked into several GitHub discussion, none of which have addressed my issue.

Comment: could you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: can you specify the project structure, that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use the `Reload JavaScript Project` command once I opened up a JavaScript file within the project. Apparently, that command is only available in *.js* and *.jsx* files.

However, this only worked part of the time. By stoping my running project and reloading VSCode - `Developer: Reload Window` - I was able get both the IntelliSense and webpack project to work.

Comment: Did not solve the issue to me. What else I could do?

Comment: @AdriánRodriguez, if you have tried everything in this thread and have explored other solutions on the site, I recommend you open a new question and describe your specific issue.

Comment: Thanks @Connor, I kept reading and I realised that because of create-react-app and webpack I needed an overload of extra configuration, creating a plugin, install another library, etc. So I'll keep this in stand by until I can switch the project to Vite.